# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException from WebClient.UploadString method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have looked at some of the similar questions and none seem to quite fit what we are ocassionally experiencing in our production systems.

We have an ASP.NET MVC (4.8) application that makes use of WebClient.UploadString to make an HTTP POST to our own API (residing on the same machine just on another IIS site) with an assorted few payloads, nothing crazy in size but the API that recieves them can sometimes take a long time to perform the work.

We are sometimes observing the following error:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream, CompletionDelegate completionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String method, String data)
```

From looking at the .NET Web Client source code, it can indeed sometimes catch a ThreadAbortException and re-throw it (I know this is expected behaviour) so we understand how the exception can be thrown, but unable to re-produce *why* it is thrown.

I've tried re-producing this by creating the following scenarios - all of which error, but don't yield the ThreadAbortException.

- Have an API endpoint which uses an infinite Thread.Sleep to simulate an ever-running process and see if the MVC site eventually throws a thread abort exception - it doesn't, it eventually times out.
- Make a request from the MVC Application to the API that lasts for 60s and then kill the API application while the MVC application is still going - this gets a remote server error but not Thread abort.
- Run the MVC application in isolation and run the API on IIS, make a request from the MVC application and then kill IIS hosting the API - this also gets a remote server error but not a Thread abort.

Does anyone know what can actually trigger a Thread Abort Exception from the above stack trace? Because all we can see is the .NET framework handling it - not actually throwing it - so assuming it's coming from within OSSOCK.recv - what could actually cause this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: That call to `System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle, ...)` means that the handle is taken from a safe handle calling `DangerousGetHandle()`. One of the reasons why WebClient is deprecated is because it has a hard time handling concurrent requests (subject to exploits). If you're using this class concurrently (in any way), then move to HttpClient (which you should test in this context). Or move to HttpClient anyway, since, well, WebClient / HttpWebRequest are deprecated